# how can I print a four row and column numbers from one to four and restart after it reaches four

Tags: java, loops

I feel like the code I wrote is wrong but I don't know why. looks very unprofessional to me.

```
/* 1234
   2341
   3412
   4123
*/
public class pattern{
  public static void main(String args[]){
   for(i=1; i<=4; i++)
     {for(j=1; j<=4; j++)
       {System.out.print(i);
        }
       System.out.println();
        while(i>4)
         { int i= 1;
           i++;
          System.out.print(i);}
         System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: First off, this code is just wrong. `string` nor `system` (lowercase 's') are classes. `i` and `j` are never declared. Second, this code is *horribly* formatted.

Comment: your while loop is an infinite loop. you are initializing the counter inside the loop

Comment: How does your while loop work? Your condition is that i is > 4, but inside the loop you initialise i to 1, and then add one to it, so it becomes 2. Moreover, many other problems such as wrong capitalisation, failure to initialise for loop variables, insufficient closing braces, wrong indentation, ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what your asking for exactly, but—judging from the comment above your class—you're probably looking for something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < i + 4; j++) {
        System.out.print((j % 4) + 1);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

It goes without saying, but I have to; you should always try to follow the Java naming/formatting standards.

Answer (score 0):

Take care at these:

```
 for(int i=1; i<=4; i++)
 {for(int j=1; j<=4; j++)

     System.out.println();
```

You should initialize the variables `i` and `j` and `System` not `system`
And the parameter in main method should be like `String args`:

```
   public static void main(String args[]){
```

Here is your code in nice format:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < i + 4; j++) {
            System.out.print((j % 4) + 1);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Comment: Even with the fixed formatting/indentation, the code doesn't print the correct values since his original code works incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1;i<=4;i++) {
            for(int j=1;j<=4;j++) {
                int k=i+j-1;
                if(k>4) {
                    System.out.print(k-4 + " ");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(k + " ");
                }

            }
            System.out.print(" ");
```